# Parallel md5sum on all *.txt files in directory

Tags: bash, hashsum, gnu-parallel

Trying to calculate md5 hash of all `*.txt` files in directory and store each in same filename but with extension replaced from `.txt` to `.md5`.

For file: `foo.txt`
i want to create file: `foo.md5`
with content:

`9fa74bee342222aadd999b2e8b2bef62 *foo.txt`

I have managed to get needed files with command below, but I wonder is there some much shorter alternative, or at least a way to drop one or two `awk` commands?

`time find *.txt | parallel md5sum | awk '{ print $1, $2, $2 }' | awk '{$1 $2 $3 > gsub(".txt", ".md5", $3); print}' | awk '{ print $1, "*"$2 > $3 }'`

I have found some alternatives, but they don't use parallel and the just add .md5 to filename, not replace it. Also they store only md5 hash, I need this `*filename` modification.

Comment: Your script will fail on spaces or newlines in filename. And if there are same filenames with only different extension (okay, you only use `.txt`, I would still go with `file.ext.md5` instead of `file.md5`)

Comment: You are correct, script is not for general purpose. But this files are machine generated so I know there are no spaces and no other extensions + I need to keep backward compatibility so this is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function and run with `parallel`:

```bsh
_md5(){
  md5sum -b "$1" > "$1.md5"
}
export -f _md5

parallel -j8 _md5 ::: *.txt
```

Use `"${1%.*}".md5` to replace the extension with `md5` instead of appending it.

Comment: This will create `9fa74bee342222aadd999b2e8b2bef62 foo.txt` instead of `9fa74bee342222aadd999b2e8b2bef62 *foo.txt` but OK. Don't ask why but backward compatibility sucks.

Comment: FWIW, the `md5sum` I have on Debian adds the `*` if it's told to read the file in binary mode, i.e. `md5sum -b`.

Comment: @ikkacu. You're hero, this is also stated in `man md5sum`: `The default mode is to  print a line with checksum, a space, a character indicating input  mode  ('*'  for  binary,  ' ' for text or where binary is insignificant), and    name for each FILE.`

Comment: Added `-b` to `md5sum` in the function!

Comment: right, "[space] for text _or when binary is insignificant_". As in all Unixen, basically...

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs
m5() md5sum < $1 > $1:r.md5
zargs -l1 -rP8 -- **/*.txt(ND.) -- m5
```

Or with GNU utilities and any shell:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 |
  xargs -r0 -l1 -P8 sh -c 'exec md5sum < "$1" > "${1%.*}.md5"' sh
```

Comment: Cool alternatives, will need to try this and decode all cmd params when I catch some time :)